# Is there any performance implication in Snowflake when using stage + storage integration vs direct storage integration for data loading / unloading?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

If I have an AWS S3 storage integration and a stage pointing to that stage:

```
create stage my_stage
  storage_integration = my_storage_integration
  url = 's3://mybucket/'
  ;
```

Is there any performance difference between running these two commands:

```
COPY INTO ... from 's3://mybucket/myfile.csv' storage_integration=my_storage_integration;
COPY INTO ... FROM '@my_stage/myfile.csv';
```

In general, is there any difference in processing between using a stage vs a storage integration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The storage integration is only to avoid storing AWS access key and secret key in Snowflake. It does **not have any impact on the performance**.

So instead having a S3 stage with embedded AWS access keys and secret key. You can have the S3 stage point to a storage integration.
The storage integration does not have AWS credentials/secrets per se. You provide the ARN of an IAM role in your AWS account with access to the S3 buckets that you want to load from/unload to. Then the storage integration provides you with a snowflake iam user arn and an external ID that you can use to set a trust relationship from the role in your account to that snowflake user.

Then when you access the stage Snowflake will assume the aws role in your account and therefore will be access the S3 bucket without you having to provide aws credentials.